# How to delete rows from Cassandra column family using non key column?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to delete multiple rows from Cassandra CF using CQL/Pig/Hive query without using key in the filter condition?

Something like DELETE FROM `[ColumnFamily] WHERE [NonKeyColumnName] = [Value]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with CQL as it needs at the very least the partition part of the row key.

If you were using playOrm, you can retrieve objects with Scalable-SQL without using the row key!!!! and then delete them, but there is no way with CQL.

For Hive and Pig, these are typically using map/reduce so you should be able to do it but you need to send them out into the map/reduce job and read in every row int he column family.

later,
Dean